# How can I average number of items in our SQLite database by 24-hour period?

Tags: sqlite, date, average

Trying to create a report for our support ticketing system and I'm trying to have 2 results in the report that show a rolling average of how many tickets were opened in a day and how many were closed in a day.

Basically, query the entire tickets table, separate out everything by individual days that the tickets were created on, count the number tickets for each individual day, then average that number.

My friend gave me this query:

```
SELECT AVG(ticket_count)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ticket_count FROM tickets
GROUP BY DATE(created_at, '%Y'), DATE(created_at, '%m'), DATE(created_at, '%d')) AS ticket_part
```

But it's not seeming to work for me. All I get is a single result with the number of tickets created last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle part of your query is collapsing the table to a single row, so the outer part has nothing upon which to group.  It's hard to say exactly what you need without seeing the schema for ticket_count, but at a guess I'd try this:

```
SELECT
  AVG(CAST(TicketsOpened AS REAL))  -- The cast to REAL ensures that { 1, 2 } averages to 1.5 rather than 1
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS Day  -- The cast to DATE truncates any time element; if you're storing date alone, you can omit this
    COUNT(*) AS TicketsOpened
  FROM
    ticket_count
  GROUP BY
    CAST(created_at AS DATE)
  ) AS X
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, no date types in Sqlite?  For reals?  If you're using text fields for your dates, use "LEFT(created_as, 10)" instead of "CAST(created_at AS DATE)".

Comment: There's no date type, but there's a `DATE` *function* to which you can pass a 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' string and get 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: The result doesn't seem quite right on this one either. When I run the query, the result I get is 1443.333. Problem is, the database has ~4300 tickets that span the course of 1 year 2 months, so that's definitely not a daily average...more like a quarterly average.

Comment: Ahh...I figured it out. Instead of using a CAST(created_at AS DATE), with SQLite you can use date(created_at) to get it to return just the date portion of what's stored.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what finally worked for me:

```
SELECT round(CAST(AVG(TicketsOpened) AS REAL), 1) as DailyOpenAvg
FROM
(SELECT date(created_at) as Day, COUNT(*) as TicketsOpened
FROM tickets
GROUP BY date(created_at)
) AS X
```